# References to objects of different classes

Tags: java, reference

I have a tank class and an item class. In the tank class in the constructor I save the tank items with an arraylist.

tank class

```
public class Tank{

private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String imageBackground;
private double length;
private double height;
private double width;
private double temperature;
private int ph;

private List<Item> items;

public Tank() throws TankException{
    this("D1","Default", "Tank Default", 50.25, 10.55, 100.232, "./", 15, 7);
}


public Tank(String id, String name, String description, double length, double height, double width, String imageBackground, double temperature, int ph) throws TankException {
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setDescription(description);
    setLength(length);
    setHeight(height);
    setWidth(width);
    setImageBackground(imageBackground);
    setTemperature(temperature);
    setPh(ph);
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();      
}
```

class item

```
public abstract class Item extends ImageView{

private static int nextId = 0;
private double xCoord, yCoord; //location
private double length, height; // define size of item
private String spriteImage;
private Tank tank;

protected Item(double xCoord, double yCoord, String spriteImage, double length, double height, Tank tank) throws ItemException {
    setId("I"+nextId); 
    nextId++;

    setLocation(xCoord,yCoord);
    setSpriteImage(spriteImage);        
    setLength(length);
    setHeight(height);      
    setTank(tank);
}
```

Now they ask me to add a new class called keeper which has to have three attributes:
id, name, surname.

Besides they ask me to keep the references to the items of the tanks for which the keeper is responsible.

In tanks we should not keep the caretaker / s responsible.

The maximum number of tanks that each keeper can care for is 5.

But I don't know if what I did is correct, create an item type object in keeper and a 5 position arraylist in tank.

This is my code class keeper:

```
public class Keeper {

private int id;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private Item itemstanques;


protected Keeper(int id, String nombre, String apellido) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
}
```

and in the tank class I added 5 position arraylist

> ```
>  private List<Keeper> keeper;
> ```

and constructor

> ```
>   public Tank(String id, String name, String description, double length, double height, double 
>     width, String imageBackground, double temperature, int ph) throws TankException {
>     setId(id);
>     setName(name);
>     setDescription(description);
>     setLength(length);
>     setHeight(height);
>     setWidth(width);
>     setImageBackground(imageBackground);
>     setTemperature(temperature);
>     setPh(ph);
>     items = new ArrayList<Item>();
>     keeper=new ArrayList<Keeper>(4);
> }
> ```

Is this correct?

Comment: IMO tank should have keeper field and the keeper should have array of tanks, also if it should have fixed size of array it should be array instead of list, if you want list you will need to do some logic to check if size is below 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can see how it's getting confusion for you. Keep in mind it always depends on the requirements so I may be interpreting this wrong. But I would say it makes sense that a tank has a list of items, but inside the tank class it could just be a reference to a list of items. Then in your main when you create your tank you can have a sperate method to add items. So tank class might look like:

```
public class Tank{
.
.
.
private List<Item> items;

public Tank(String id, String name, String description, double length, double height, double width, String imageBackground, double temperature, int ph, List<Item> tankItems) throws TankException {
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setDescription(description);
    setLength(length);
    setHeight(height);
    setWidth(width);
    setImageBackground(imageBackground);
    setTemperature(temperature);
    setPh(ph);
    this.items = tankItems;      
}
```

Then in your main you could add your list:

```
public class Match {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tank tank1 = new Tank("D1","Default", "Tank Default"
                           , 50.25, 10.55, 100.232, "./"
                           , 15, 7, addItems());
    }

   public static List<Items> addItems(){
      //build your list of tankItems here of items
      .
      .
      return tankItems;
   }
}
```

Based on how I am reading it and my explanation above I would remove tank from the Item class. It's not clear that a item needs to be associated with a tank but it's up to you.

In your keeper class sounds like 1 keeper can maintain 5 tanks so one approach would be:

```
public class keeper {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private List<tank> tanks;
    private boolean estoyLlena;


    protected Keeper(int id, String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.estoyLlena = false;
        tanks = null;
    }

    public boolean addTankToKeeper(Tank aTank) {

        if(this.tanks.size() < 5) {
            this.tanks.add(aTank);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

hope that helps.